# Creating .inp file in matlab

Tags: matlab, interface, element, abaqus

I'm relatively new to abaqus and currently working on an optimisation project for a beam under concentrated load where I have to run multiple files with different parameters(length,width,load) in matlab to create a .inp file to be run on abaqus. My question is, how would I go about tackling this problem and is there a way to generate the nodes and elements automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize your Abaqus project using the Python interface. It requires some getting used to, but it can be quite powerful depending on what you want to do. I assume your optimizer is programmed in Matlab, but that should not be a problem. You can write a wrapper function in Matlab which calls Abaqus with the script you want. The command would be `abaqus cae noGUI=<script.py>` to run the script that creates your input file.

Alternatively you can create a base input file and create a script that looks for the lines that have to be changed. This can be based on the input file keywords, you can put some own parameters (dummy words) that you substitute using your script or a comment that can easily be recognized.

The best approach depends a bit on what exactly you want to change.

Abaqus also offers some parameterization, I think [this link](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEMODRefMap/simamod-c-parinput.htm) may be handy.

Comment: Hi Henri, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this project requires me to create the input file only using a single script in Matlab, the model created on Abaqus being the by product of it. So using a python interface isn't an option. For the alternative, how would I create the base input file from scratch using Matlab? An example or a link to doing this would also be helpful.

Comment: For the alternative option you can create the base  input file for one sample in your design space using Abaqus CEA and for the other samples use Matlab to read it, parse it and substitute the parameters you want to create the other samples, then finally save it as a new input file. It's not literally "from scratch". To me it really seems like overkill to have it built from scratch as most lines will be the same between all evaluations of your designs (and .inp files can be quite long depending on your case).

Comment: Yes, it can be a long process. So what I decided to do is build the base input file of a simple beam on Abaqus as you've suggested. But because the script I have to create in Matlab needs to be independent, I used the input lines as the base to get Matlab to print and create its own input file. Using the Abaqus keyword manual to change specific commands.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding generating the nodes and elements automatically, it very much possible but it is time consuming and rather complicated process. 
Nodes can be created by defining the `x`,`y` and `z` coordinates and Elements can be created by defining the `Nodal Connectivity`. As the model gets complicated, defining the `x`,`y` and `z` coordinates and `Nodal Connectivity` also get difficult. However, for simple models you can still create the nodes and elements automatically. 
 If I am guessing correctly, your model is rectangular shaped beam, hence creating mesh may not be complicated.
In `Abaqus`,  `Nodal Connectivity` for each element type is given in `Analysis Help Manuals`. Following is the example of `Nodal Connectivity` for `4-Noded Quad` and `8-Noded Hex` Element.
[image: Nodal Connectivity for Quad and Linear Hex Elements]

To get you started, I am providing here the `Python` code to create Abaqus INPUT mesh file for 2D and 3D beam (Later you can replicate in MATLAB code):

```
fnm = 'shell.inp'
w = 100  # x-direction
h = 10  # y-direction
npx = 30;    npy = 5

fout = open(fnm, 'w')
# Creating node information
fout.write('*Node, Nset=All_Nodes\n')
nds = [];   elms = []
for i in range(npy):
    y = (i+1)/npy * h
    for j in range(npx):
        nid = i*npx + j + 1
        x = (j+1)/npx * w
        nds.append([nid,x,y,0.0])
        fout.write('%10d,%10f,%10f,%10f\n'%(nid,x,y,0.0))

# Creating Nodal connectivity
fout.write('*Element, Type=S4, Elset=All_Elements\n')
for m in range(npy-1):
    for n in range(npx-1):
        eid = m*(npx-1) + n + 1
        e1 = n + 2 + npx + m*npx
        e2 = e1 - 1
        e3 = n + 1 + m*npx
        e4 = e3 + 1
        elms.append([eid,e1,e2,e3,e4])
        fout.write(('%10d,'*4+'%10d\n')%(eid,e1,e2,e3,e4))

fout.close()

# ====================================================================

fnm = 'rect_beam.inp'
w = 10      # z-direction
h = 10      # y-direction
l = 100     # X-direction
npx = 20;npy = 5;npz = 3

fout = open(fnm, 'w')
# Creating node information
fout.write('*Node, Nset=All_Nodes\n')
nds = [];elms = []
for i in range(npz):
    z = (i+1)/npz * w
    for j in range(npy):
        y = (j+1)/npy * h
        for k in range(npx):
            nid = i*(npx*npy) + j*npx + k + 1
            x = (k+1)/npx * l
            nds.append([nid,x,y,z])
            fout.write('%10d,%10f,%10f,%10f\n'%(nid,x,y,z))

# Creating Nodal connectivity
fout.write('*Element, Type=C3D8, Elset=All_Elements\n')
for m in range(npz-1):
    for n in range(npy-1):
        for p in range(npx-1):
            eid = m*(npy-1)*(npx-1) + n*(npx-1) + p + 1
            e1 = p + 2 + npx + n*npx + m*npx*npy
            e2 = e1 - 1
            e3 = p + 1 + n*npx + m*npx*npy
            e4 = e3 + 1
            e5 = e1 + (npx*npy)
            e6 = e5 - 1
            e7 = e3 + (npx*npy)
            e8 = e7 + 1
            elms.append([eid,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8])
            fout.write(('%6d,'*8+'%6d\n')%(eid,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8))
            print(m,n,p,'|',eid,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8)
fout.close()
```

Comment: Satish, thank you for your help! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out and do. I've replicated it on Matlab but theres a few things I dont understand. Firstly, the 'npx' and 'npy' variables do they represent? Secondly, the equations used to determine the nodal coordinates and Nodal connectivity would you mind explaining how you got this? Because I've looked through the keyword manaul and couldn't find an equation used for this purpose.

Comment: Firstly, `npx` and `npy` are the total number of nodes you want in `x` and `y` direction resp.. These variables are used just to have control over mesh density (coarse or finer). and Secondly, regarding `Nodal Connectivity`, there are no equations specified in `Abaqus` Manual as such, however there are certain sequencing of node `Abaqus` input file follows to define a element. For ex. As shown in 1st figure, if you want to create a element from nodes 1,2,3 and 4, then you must specify `<element number>, 1,2,3,4`  in the input file after `*Element, Type=S4` line (direction is clock-wise).

Comment: Just a follow up question, I've attempted to extract the first and last nid values so that the process can be automated when different parameter were chosen. I tried do this by storing it as an array and then extracting it for the Nset before moving onto doing it for the Elset. But I keep on getting errors, would you mind looking at the script to identifying where i went wrong? [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r1m91PgrmCIO-xerNO5j1JJ8HpQr-Jlx/view?usp=sharing)_ italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: Okay, I checked your code. You missed out on one basic difference between Python and MATLAB. They have different indexing technique. Python indexing starts from 0 whereas MATLAB starts from 1. In your code, in for loop you start from 0 instead of 1.